# grafana + graphite + failed on test connection

Tags: linux, hadoop, graphite, grafana

first I'm new to Grafana so excuse me if i don't use the right words to describe my issue

I installed  Grafana + Graphite solution in my ambari cluster
( I am using ambari cluster with graphite service )
graphite service is working fine on the Ambari cluster

and when I connect the grafana as **http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3000**
and then try to perform **test connection** on test connection button

I get

```
unknown error :
cannot read property 'message' of null
```

please advice why this happend and what to fix here?

on my linux machine ( versions )

```
rpm -qa | grep grafana
ambari-metrics-grafana-2.5.0.3-7.x86_64

rpm -qa | grep graphite
graphite2-1.2.2-5.el7.x86_64
graphite-web-0.9.15-1.el7.noarch
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a known bug in earlier versions of Grafana, that was fixed in 3.0, can you try to update the package. If your package version corresponds with Grafana versioning it is pretty old.

[Bug info](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/4499)